# Creating multiple pages

Tags: crystal-reports

On Crystal Reports I have a {field} that ranges from 1 to 50, so I want to create a title, page 1 of {field} and also make each page correspondent to the total amount.
So if {field} is 3 then:

Page 1 of 3
--------New Page----------
Page 2 of 3
--------New Page----------
Page 3 of 3

Any ideas?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Create a group based on your {field}, and in group header section choose the option "New page before" (probably not the exact phrase, I'm using a non-english gui language).

If your field has always all values 1 to 50, then I'd sort by this field, and use the builtin page numbering function to create the "Page n of m" texts. If not, you could create it yourself in a formula.